# Failure sending e-mail in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms

Here's my code. I know that this is a duplicate question but I have visited all the links in staqckoverflow and codeproject but still I am unable to get an answer.

```
try
    {
        MailMessage mailmessage = new MailMessage();
        mailmessage.To.Add("xxx.com");
        mailmessage.From = new MailAddress("xxx.com");
        mailmessage.Subject = "Transaction sent for Verification ";
        mailmessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpAdd"].ToString());
        smtpClient.Send(mailmessage);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mailalert", "alert('" + "Mail sent for verification" + "');", true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Response.Write("Could not send E-mail- error: " + ex.Message);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mailfailure", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error trace.

Comment: the error message is Failure to send mail. I mean exception message

Comment: Please check the inner exception. There are many potencial causes (wrong smtp, missed credentials, etc)

Comment: it's showing a Java exception error at some line in the smtp address.

Comment: As Claudio said, please post the actual text of the InnerException.  It really helps to know what it's saying and a "java" exception would be a very odd one.

Comment: Are you testing locally? or on a test server? Have you created a smaller test case outside of asp.net to see if you can even send emails? Your email server may need to grant permissions, you may need credentials, port/host info etc... Start smaller to verify you can send emails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("To_address"));
        msg.Subject = "You have a WebMail!!";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = "Message";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your mail address", "your password");
        smtp.Host = "host name";
        smtp.Port = "host number";
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        smtp.Send(msg);
```